# Rails - null DateTime in response

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, time

I am using Rails 4, ruby 2.0, and my_sql.
In my table, I have a "created_at" column which is handled by rails itself.
When I query the table:

```
 results = Table1.select("created_at",...etc)
 results.each do |result|
    hash[:date]=result.created_at
 ....
 then later in the code, I render "hash" as a json response.
```

The value of :date in the json response is "null".

I tried :

```
results.each do |result|
    puts result.created_at
```

And I am getting the date in the console.

Any help ?

**EDIT:**

If I change the type of the column from "datetime" to "timestamp"... It works.

How to do this with column type "datetime"?

Comment: I think this will help you do as: " hash[:date] = result.created_at.to_s "

Comment: nope ... its giving an empty string in the json response